# Didn't the title and formatting assistants violate OpenAI's policy for Sharing and Publication?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

From the [Sharing & publication policy](https://openai.com/policies/sharing-publication-policy) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230712083124/https://openai.com/policies/sharing-publication-policy)):

> ### Content co-authored with the OpenAI API
>
> Creators who wish to publish their first-party written content (e.g., a book, compendium of short stories) created in part with the OpenAI API are permitted to do so under the following conditions:
>
> - [...]
> - The role of AI in formulating the content is clearly disclosed in a way that no reader could possibly miss, and that a typical reader would find sufficiently easy to understand.
> - [...]
>
> For instance, one must detail in a Foreword or Introduction (or some place similar) the relative roles of drafting, editing, etc. People should not represent API-generated content as being wholly generated by a human or wholly generated by an AI, and it is a human who must take ultimate responsibility for the content being published.
>
> Here is some stock language you may use to describe your creative process, provided it is accurate:
>
> > The author generated this text in part with GPT-3, OpenAI’s large-scale language-generation model. Upon generating draft language, the author reviewed, edited, and revised the language to their own liking and takes ultimate responsibility for the content of this publication.

To my knowledge, neither the title-generator nor the formatting assistant included any such notices into the post, right?

As for why I feel confident that these projects used OpenAI things, I once got "*As an AI language model, I [...]*" when fiddling with the formatting assistant. To me, that spells it out pretty clearly.

Comment: That seems like a pretty blatant violation indeed... Unless there's some different set of rules for a cooperate contract?

Comment: Was there anything in the activity history like when a question created in the wizard has *"created from wizard"*?

Comment: @ThomA I don't think the revision history page qualifies for "_clearly disclosed in a way that no reader could possibly miss_" Nobody who wasn't told to their face would know to look for that there if it was there.

Comment: I'm not saying that it was clear, but wondered if it was even disclosed at all.

Comment: "Created from wizard" isn't what I am getting at, @ErikA ... That is an example what what *currently* happens when a user uses the wizard. I am asking *if* there *was* something different for when the AI suggested was accepted in the activity history.

Comment: Honest question: did they use OpenAI API, or instead run the LLM on-premise?

Comment: To my knowledge they have not disclosed the source of their AI training data or if they were using OpenAI at all for it.

Comment: @TylerH I once got "_As an AI language model, I \[...\]_" when fiddling with the formatting assistant. To me, that spells it out pretty clearly.

Comment: @AndrewT. isn't the LLM... super hecking expensive to run? (from my quick googling, and memory of Zoe making links saying something like "disgustingly expensive hype train")

Comment: Additional issues: A) using the AI title-generator without following the [referencing requirements](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is a violation of the [Code of Conduct: Inauthentic usage policy](//stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage), which requires following the referencing requirements for all work from "other online and offline tools"; and B) posting it attempts to have the OP grant a CC BY-SA license for it, which asserts OP has copyright over that content, which is, *at best*, unsettled legal ground for copyright of AI produced content.

Comment: @Makyen yeah. Note on B, [OpenAI's ToU states](https://openai.com/policies/terms-of-use#3-content): "_Subject to your compliance with these Terms, OpenAI hereby assigns to you all its right, title and interest in and to Output._" Not sure how much that's worth (if anything at all).

Comment: @starball [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389060/2023-layoff-impacting-58-so-se-staff-2023-05-10#comment1297351_389060). In April, CGPT was estimated to cost [over 700000 USD per day](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-much-chatgpt-costs-openai-to-run-estimate-report-2023-4?r=US&IR=T). There's probably newer estimates somewhere. The servers required for a large-scale deployed LLM have to have an enormous amount of computational throughput, which also means a lot of servers are required (again, at a large scale), and all of them run at a high load which also means high power use

Comment: Most of these servers also use specialised AI hardware (which is basically GPUs with AI optimisations, that suck as much as 400 watts each). I doubt Stack runs their own servers. One Nvidia A100 costs around [10000 USD](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/02/23/nvidias-a100-is-the-10000-chip-powering-the-race-for-ai-.html). Another quote from the article: "At that rate, Microsoft would need over 20,000 8-GPU servers just to deploy the model in Bing to everyone, suggesting Microsoft’s feature could cost $4 billion in infrastructure spending."

Comment: SO isn't near that scale, but even then, one pre-built AI server costs 200k USD (also from the CNBC article). Seeing as they had to fire 10% of their staff because they can't manage their finances, I strongly doubt they can afford the number of servers required for even a limited deployment. No clue how they deployed it. Using OpenAI's API directly and paying them seems like the most obvious option (it's still expensive, but it saves them the upfront costs). In either case, it's almost guaranteed GPT, but what terms they use it under is probably in a deal we'll never get the details of.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike yes, I imagine they are using the API- probably a cheaper model for an experiment. I attempted a rough cost estimate for the API usage [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390305/997587). Not sure how close I was to the actual cost.

Comment: The OpenAI requirement is also in line with the EU AI draft, specifically Art 52. This is not a high-risk AI, so there will be few requirements, but informing the user is one of the remaining obligations.