# OverflowAI Alpha invitation emails were distributed in error Nov 28th

Tags: discussion, overflow-ai

Stack Overflow is currently in the process of rolling out invitations to [access OverflowAI alpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426432/overflowai-search-is-now-available-for-alpha-testing-september-13-2023) to 200 users per day.

Today, the process we use to grant access to the OverflowAI Alpha did not work as expected and sent access emails to ***all users*** who had joined the waitlist to participate. However, because we are limiting expansion to around 200 users per day, only 200 of the emails sent (a small proportion) contain valid links to join the Alpha. The majority of users who received these access emails today will find that their access links do not work as expected, and we apologize for the inconvenience and confusion.

All affected users will receive a correction email today to apologize for the confusion. We will continue to roll out access to waitlisted participants at a rate of around 200 users per day. Users who were waitlisted before today are still on the waitlist for the OverflowAI Alpha - no further action is needed.

**Update:** <s>Emails are now going out to affected waitlisted participants. Please check your inbox for further clarification.</s> Emails have been sent to all affected users who were waitlisted for the OverflowAI Alpha. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: people who only look at questions in collectives with articles [will not see this featured post](/q/426454/11107541). are you going to send out an email telling everyone you incorrectly emailed about this? because that's what I expect to get.

Comment: @starball All affected users will receive a correction by email.

Comment: I got two emails. Both are invalid?

Comment: @SmartManoj as stated in the post if you are affected you will receive an email clarifying that your account is still on the waitlist and apologizing for the confusion.

Comment: Prolly went to old (dead) work email that it seems is impossible to remove from your records despite providing 2 working emails.

Comment: Can Stack not bungle something related to "AI"? Absolutely ridiculous

Comment: Sounds to me like the AI-powered e-mail stack overflowed.