# Sunsetting the OverflowAI working group Team and moving feedback to Meta

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, overflow-ai

Over the last several months, we have gathered feedback for OverflowAI during our alpha phase. This feedback has so far taken place in three locations: in [a working group](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426432/overflowai-search-is-now-available-for-alpha-testing-september-13-2023) hosted on Stack Overflow for Teams, in direct interviews with users, and by monitoring posts on Meta. As participation in the alpha grows, we want to ensure that everyone's voice can be heard and that we continue to scale our feedback process effectively. To achieve this, we are sunsetting the working group on Teams. We’ll be focusing our efforts primarily on collecting and responding to feedback on Meta, and potentially conducting further user interviews.

Starting today, all feedback, discussions, and suggestions for the OverflowAI alpha should be posted on Meta.

To ensure that your feedback is properly surfaced, please use the [overflow-ai](/questions/tagged/overflow-ai) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tags when posting questions. You can then [flag the post for escalation by requesting the moderator team add the [status-review] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/208518). Using the appropriate tags will help your feedback be seen and handled effectively.

We're incredibly grateful for the dedication and input of the working group thus far. Your contributions have set a strong foundation for this next phase of the alpha.

If you’re not yet part of the alpha and are interested in joining the waitlist, go to your account preferences or [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/) and toggle the “Enable OverflowAI Search” opt-in option. If you are currently on the waitlist, stay tuned as we continue to expand the alpha group every day!

As always, your participation and feedback are the driving forces behind our development process. Thank you again for your continued support and engagement.

Comment: Will the feedback posted in said private team ever be made public?

Comment: We are especially interested in the contributions from user "Skynet". I don't trust that guy.

Comment: @KevinB it's... really not especially interesting. It's mostly what you'd expect: it hallucinates or chooses suboptimal sources sometimes, a list of votable answer links with no indication of what they contributed specifically is bad, various minor UI issues, etc. Given that the feedback was given in a non-public environment, releasing it verbatim could be problematic without first contacting those users. It could be summarized, but...eh, I don't see a lot of value there. However, I think it might be good to clarify to participants that they can, if they so choose, repost their feedback here.

Comment: That's not to say that people didn't provide useful feedback, of course. I'm just not sure it would provide a lot of value to release publicly.

Comment: So the project has gone, completely unchanged since launch, with no information from staff on how it's performing? Despite being something that has the potential to be quite impactful on how the site operates? We've literally seen nothing about how this is doing since it launched.