# Concluding the OverflowAI Search Alpha on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, search, announcement, overflow-ai

[Six months ago we announced OverflowAI Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426432/overflowai-search-is-now-available-for-alpha-testing-september-13-2023) and began welcoming users to alpha test this new feature. We have gone through extensive user feedback; Alpha testers started over 25,000 conversations and performed around 100,000 searches. We are deeply grateful for the time and energy alpha participants put into trying out and reviewing this new feature of the site.

However, due to [evolution in our OverflowAI strategy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/03/27/community-products-reflections-and-looking-ahead/), we have made the decision to ramp down the testing of the conversational search and search summarization features.

#### Changes we are making as part of the ramp-down process

Within the next few weeks, we will be making several changes to ramp down access to the OverflowAI Search alpha. Participants in the OverflowAI Search alpha will no longer have access to our conversational search or search summarization feature. We will also be removing the waitlist option on profile pages and on Stack Overflow Labs until further notice. Users who were participating in the alpha test will be sent a notification email as well, thanking them for their interest and participation, and explaining that their access to these alpha features will be removed.

To those of you who have signed up, we are again very grateful for your contributions and interest.

Though our testing with our Alpha version of OverflowAI Search has come to a close, we are far from idle. We hope you’ll have [quite a lot to look forward to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398734/upcoming-initiatives-on-stack-overflow-and-across-the-stack-exchange-network) throughout this upcoming April. It will be a busy month!

Comment: If I read this correctly, it either means you have gathered enough data and concluded that the feature can go live or you have gathered enough data and concluded the feature isn't needed anymore. Some kind of outlook on planned next actions for this AI Search would be nice.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution or they gathered enough data during this first phase, and want to implement some changes before conducting further experiments. Or they have infrastructure issues or ... I mean it's not limited to the options you listed.

Comment: @M-- To me the two options seemed like the most likely ones. If only there was more conclusion in the concluding.

Comment: Or Google paid them to not compete with whatever Google's doing with the content Google bought.